# I am able to create a table in oracle -- but not use desc or insert

Tags: oracle

I am brand new to Oracle 11g. I login to SQL plus and create a table like this.

```
SQL> create table "Skills" ("SkillID" Number(20), "Level" Number(20), "Area" Varchar2(20));

Table created.
```

But then I try to insert into or describe the table and it does not work.

```
SQL> desc skills;
ERROR:
ORA-04043: object skills does not exist
```

It does not appear to be a simple issue of case-sensitivity:

```
SQL> desc Skills;
ERROR:
ORA-04043: object Skills does not exist
```

I don't understand why I am seemingly able to create the table but then unable to call up its structure or add in data. What's going on? It is not a permissions issue because I am able to insert into other tables I have created on the account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating the table as "Skills", instead of "skills".  By using the quotes, you specify that the table name should be case sensitive.  Try `desc "Skills"` and see if that works better for you.

Comment: Brilliant @ScottS! akh2103 - I'd suggest *not* using double quotes unless you absolutely need them. You're likely to run into other weird problems if you continue with them.

Comment: @EdGibbs you were right: it was the quotes. I tried it with no quotes around the table name and it works. i just saw the quotes syntax in some tutorial and copied it. If you write as answer I will accept. Also, see edit on case sensitivity. Tx.

Comment: I agree completely with EdGibbs - don't use quotes if you don't need them, and I've never encountered a situation where I needed them.

Comment: akh2103 - you should accept the @ScottS answer. He's the one who figured out that the quotes were the problem. I just kinda added on.

Comment: akh2103 - as for the edit on case sensitivity, Oracle and SQLPlus are case insensitive by default, so `SKILLS` and `Skills` and `skills` are all the same to them. They only care about case when you use the double quotes, which is why Scott's answer is The One.